# Lambda Expression not filtering result

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, lambda, ienumerable

Hi I am having trouble with the following, the first part appears to be retuning all the results I need to create my filters, although I seem to be having a hard time with that. The second part should filter the the first part by the role, except it is retuning two results, the "Expedite" and the alternative role. the result is it always selects the alternative role. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My code is as follows

```
// group by unique key POPOrderReturnLineID
 IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, ExpediteDataDTO>> GroupedExpediteData =
 GetDirtyExpediteData()
 .ToList()
 .GroupBy(expediteItem => expediteItem.POPOrderReturnLineID)
 ;


 // any item with an expedite role and a valid contact value we want to use preferably
 IEnumerable<ExpediteDataDTO> ValidExpedite = GroupedExpediteData
 .Where(groupItem =>
 .groupItem.Any(expediteItem => expediteItem.PO_Role == "Expedite"))
 .Select(groupItem =>
 groupItem.Last(expediteItem =>
 IsContactValueValid(expediteItem.ContactValue)))
 ;
```

Comment: Your second filter selects any groups that contain at least one item with the "Expedite" role - that means it could have other items with any other roles in the group. Your `Select` always picks the last item in each group, which could be any role. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback, sorry I have had to take some time away from work. The goal was to return a list of items from a po system where there dates have gone in the past i.e. over due. It then looks for the two different possible email addresses, that are in the database. where the expedite role is set and if not available fall back to the default po role. This is a third party application and database I am trying to interact with and maybe just need to break this out, I was hoping I could do it all in just the one step.